# Why .0 is dropped in division but not in +, - and *?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, decimal

**So, as per C# rules, in the division (int & int division) the output is an int. While in (FP & int division), it is a FP.**

but following generate different outputs.

```
int a = 45; //integer
decimal b = 5.0m; //floating point
Console.WriteLine(a/b); // "9"
```

Output is: 9 //output looks like an integer??? why?

Note that +, -, and `*` produce expected result:

```
  Console.WriteLine(a * b); // "225.0"
```

Dividing by non whole number produce expected result:

```
int a = 45; //integer
decimal b = 5.5m; //floating point
Console.WriteLine(a/b); // "8.181818181818181818"
```

Output is:  8.181818181818181818 - `/` output is a FP which is okay.

Can anyone explain this?

The results are more consistent for `float` / `double` - no zeros in output for all operations (which makes sense as  those types don't store infomration on number of digits after decimal point)

Comment: `output is an integer` - no. the output is a _string representation_ of the number - in both cases. if you want a specific format, use `string.Format()` - for example. also: what do you expect the output to be? `9.0`? `9.00`? `9.000`? ... (hint: save the result of your divison in a variable and inspect it with the debugger)

Comment: I expected it to be "9.0" since 5.0 was a floating point, just like 5.5 which generates output in floating point without using any string.Format() I was teaching my student the general rule for "division operator". But, I have no idea why it truncates the zero in 9.0 
P.S.
I am a teacher and teaching C# for the first time.

Comment: as a teacher you should be aware that, mathematically, `9` is equal to `9.0` and `9.00000000000000000000000000000000...`. so the program choses the shortest. just like it's printing `5.5` instead of `5.50000` (or, for example, `05.5`). also, and i don't mean any offense, but i believe it would be a smart move to have a better understanding of the basics of C# before teaching it? the [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @Amy Ask yourself why it should show the zero. i.e. why should it show the result to 1dp. Did you ask it to?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: got it, thank you for the explanation. (Sometimes a teacher has no choice but to teach an allocated course. However, I try my best to research each and every point before teaching.) Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ClickRick : Thanks for another explanation. :)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann please note that in the question uses `decimal` and `5m` is *different* from `5.0m` - so it is very fair expectation that result of the division will preserve "one digit after decimal point". So while looking absolutely stupid this question actually have solid reason to exist.

Comment: @Amy I've edited the question (and reverted the edit afterwards as it invalidates the answer) - please review the edit (via history) and see if it aligns with what you interested in. . I don't believe the interesting part of your question ("why 45/5.0m does not select more precise one digit after decimal point representation of `decimal` for division only") would really be on-topic on SO... but it is very interesting one and may actually be very popular.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thanks a lot for the edit.  I checked all the other operators and it's really interesting to see how decimal returns .0 in +, - and * but not in /

Comment: @ClickRick It's quite reasonable to see comparable presentation of the results from `Console.WriteLine(a*b);` and `Console.WriteLine(a/b);` - so... yes ~50% of reasonable folks should be surprised by `9` instead of `9.0` as result of division.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov wow.. i just checked that myself. i did _not_ know this, and i wouldn't ever have expected c# to behave that way. thanks for your update on this. (is there any explanation _why_ this behavior was chosen?)

Comment: The best explanation I have got so far (from internet) is that: "division operation will return a floating-point value if the left-hand side (dividened) is not evenly divisible by the divisor". Since 45 is evenly divisible by 5.0, we don't get a 9.0 and 45 is not evenly divisble by 5.5. I hope this is correct.

Comment: I think normally you would be doing this: FP/int (FP divided by Int) and not the other way around like I did (Int/FP). So if you divide `45.0m` by a `5` it will return value in floating point i.e. `9.0`

So it all depends upon the dividened value being a FP and it being evenly divisble.

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to think in terms of "floating point" or "not floating point" values. They're *all* floating point values. This is about either "how many significant digits are preserved" or "how many decimal places are preserved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# standard goes into details here, in [section 12.9.3](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#1293-division-operator).

> The scale of the result, before any rounding, is the closest scale to the preferred scale that will preserve a result equal to the exact result. The preferred scale is the scale of `x` less the scale of `y`.

So, to apply that, we've got `x` with a value of 45m (after an implicit conversion to `decimal`) which has a scale of 0, and `5.0m` which has a scale of 1.

Therefore the preferred scale is -1 - which would be invalid. (The scale is always non-negative.) The closest scale that can preserve the exact result is 0, so that's the *actual* scale - the result is equivalent to `9m` rather than `9.0m`.

Comment: I am sorry  but it  would  be very kind of you to look at example 2 in my update and explain why using 45.0m gives 9.0  result  but  using 5.0m in PO example  gives 9 result?

Comment: @Serge: 45.0 has a scale of 1, 5 has a scale of 0, so the "preferred scale" is 1, giving a result of 9.0. (I've explained why 45/5.0 returns 9 within the answer - that would have a negative preferred scale, so it uses 0 as the closest scale which is valid and still gives the right exact result.)

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry I must be ver dummy but i still don't understand this since for me PO example is looking the same for me -  5.0m has a scale 1, 45 has a scale 0,  so the "preferred scale" is 1, giving a result of 9.0  but it gives the result  9. The only difference is they have opposite roles.

Comment: And if try int a = 45;    decimal b = 5.000m;  you will still have  a/b=9, not 9.000

Comment: @Serge: You're subtracting the scale the wrong way round. The preferred scale is `scale(x) - scale(y)`, so 45/5.0 has a preferred scale of **-1**, not 1. Likewise 45/5.000m has a preferred scale of **-3**.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see my mistake now. I was counting a prefered scale as a maximum of both, and never thought that it shoulbe extracted in a special order.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Wow. I never really learned it that way.And, I haven't come across a book that explained this preferred scale thing. I will look in to it and try to learn how it works. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I tested and got this result

```
int a = 45; //integer
    decimal b = 5.0m; //floating point
    var r=a/b; // r is decimal
    Console.WriteLine(r);  // 9


 a = 45; //integer
     b = 5.5m; //decimal floating point
     r=a/b;   // r is decimal
    Console.WriteLine(r);  // 8.181818181818181818181818182
```

as I could see in a debuger in both casses output was decimal, not integer in the first case too

A compiler makes an implicit conversion if a result is not defined explicetly in the code. There are a lot of ways to cast types. The main rule here is 'if there are several operands in the expression, then the type of the result is the largest of the operand types'. For example, if you divide int and double, the result is double. If you multiply byte and int, the result is int.

More examples ( now with multiply)

```
    int a = 45; //integer
    
    decimal b = 5.0m; //floating point
    var rm = a*b; // rm is decimal
    Console.WriteLine(rm);  // 225.0
        
    b = 5.5m; //decimal floating point
    var r2m = a*b; // r2m is decimal
    Console.WriteLine(r2m);  // 247.5
```

UPDATE

Since the question was changed significantly by @AlexeiLevenkov and he  is asking me in comments why  .0 is dropped in division, these examples show that it is not true

```
 int a = 5; //integer


 decimal b = 45m; //floating point
 var r= b/a; // r is decimal
Console.WriteLine(r);  //  9


 b = 45.0m; //floating point
  r= b/a; // r is decimal
Console.WriteLine(r);  //  9.0

 b = 45.00m; //floating point
 var r= b/a; // r is decimal
Console.WriteLine(r);  //  9.00

 b = 45.000m; //floating point
 var r= b/a; // r is decimal
Console.WriteLine(r);  //  9.000
```

These examples show that by default a quotient has as many zerous as a dividend has.

UPDATE 2

if you try this, you will get error "Can not implicitly convert type decimal to int

```
int r = a/b; // error!!!
```

but this is OK

```
int r = a/(int)b;
```

and this is OK too

```
decimal r = a/b;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it and got the solution/asnwer why it generates output like that.

Comment: If you add explanation of output of `Console.WriteLine(a*b);` the answer would be really awesome... Without that it is really only partial answer... even if @Amy got what they wanted.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ok, check my answer again

Comment: That is an example and not an explanation - there is no reasoning why it prints "225.0" and not "225" like you'd see with `float` (I'm really interested if there actually formal explanation of division's behavior... I can reasonably see why other operations keep decimal precision)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  " 9 or 9.0 "  Why it is so important for you?   I doesn't have any practical use at all and doesnt have any impact on any code

Comment: @Serge: That's a bold assumption. Decimal is guaranteed to preserve trailing zeroes (so 1.00m and 1.0m are not the exact same value). I fail to see how you can reasonably assert that that doesn't have any impact on *any* code, unless you've actually looked at *all* the C# code that has ever been written.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am agree with you.  There is  a  difference.  I just meant this case only,  not in common, since the original question was about devision int by decimal only.  If we divide decimal by int and there is not any  reminder , the result value will be the same doesn' t matter if  it displays on the screen .00000 or no zero at all.

Comment: @Serge: Again, please don't assume that something that is irrelevant for code that *you're* writing is irrelevant for *all* code. There could easily be code that requires the output of every operation to have a specific scale, for example... in which case it's really worth understanding what determines the scale of an operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I really appreciate your help. You gave me a lot of food for thought today. For example I was just testing  45.720m/5.080m = 9, but  45.720m/5.081m =  8.99822869513875221413107656;  And now I am wondering how scaling are working in this case.

Comment: @Serge: The answer is in the piece of the standard that I quoted: "closest scale to the preferred scale that will preserve a result **equal to the exact result**". In this case an absolutely exact result isn't available, but a scale of 28 gets as close as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 45; //integer
decimal b = 5.0m; //floating point
Console.WriteLine(a/b); // why "9" and not 9.0 right?
```

---

So If I ask you what would you multiply with 5.0 to get 45? Will you be saying 9 or 9.0?

In layman's term, quotient kept as integer unless remainder exists.

Now let see whats unique about decimal.

```
double x = 10.0d; // is 10
```

But

```
decimal x = 10.0m; //is 10.0
```

> Formula for decimal : *`x.0m is x.0 and xm is x`*

> Formula for double/float : *`x.0d or xd is x`*

Now applying the formula above, look at these cases ...

10.0d + 10.0d + 10.0d *`( x.0d is x )`*

> 10 + 10 + 10 = 30

10.0d + 10.1d + 10.0d *`( x.0d is x )`*

> 10 + 10.1 + 10 = 30.1

45 * 5.0d *`( x.0d is x )`*

> 45 * 5 = 255

But...

10.0m + 10.0m + 10.0m *`( x.0m is x.0 )`*

> 10.0 + 10.0 + 10.0 = 30.0

10.0m + 10.1m + 10.0m *`( x.0m is x.0 )`*

> 10.0 + 10.1 + 10.0 = 30.1

45 * 5.0m *`( x.0m is x.0 )`*

> 45 * 5.0 = 255.0

45 * 5m *`( xm is x )`*

> 45 * 5 = 255

Now think of the division process...

> Its divisor * (quotient(0...+/-n)) till remainder becomes 0 or smaller than divisor

45/5.0m

> 5.0m * 1m..2m..3m...9m and the remainder becomes 0 here.
> END. last quotient is 9m.

But 9m is still 9 and not 9.0 right?

Comment: That's really interesting and easy to understand. Thanks a lot!